# Saving records into database throws runtime error in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I wonder why I got this runtime error by throwing this exception:

> **SqlException** was unhandled by user code
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

When I used this code below to add records into my database when in fact I always used this code every time, now its not working.

I hope you can figure out the cause of this error. Thanks...Here's the code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string conn = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Coldwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
   // SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader();

   connection.Open();
   string sql = "INSERT INTO [CommentTab]([Name],[Comments]) Values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Dispose();
   connection.Close();
   Response.Redirect("~/Default5.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What does actually contain your sql string when you execute this method? P.S. Use sql parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: can you post what are you entering inside textbox1 and textbox2; seems like a parsing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Your input contains `quotation mark("'")` itself. So better to replace them by double 
quotation mark like this

```
string Val1 =TextBox1.Text.Replace("'","''");
```

and then use this value in your query.

Comment: Thank's guys I should use parameterized stored pro.@Sachin,thanks man you made my day your code works for me.Now I realize entering strings with single quote can ruin my codes. Thanks again

Comment: Great!!! My solution has worked for you but yes @timmack You should use parameterized sql to avoid Sql injection. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in your text you are inserting. Can you post it?
Also, I'd suggest to use Store Procedure and pass parameters instead.

Comment: One of my textbox is set to multiline mode. Does this matter?

Comment: please, debug your code and see what actual string you built. If you cannot figure it out after this - please, update your post with full string.

Comment: I'm entering pure string values for TextBox1 which is name, and for textbox 2 the user can enter string or paragraph like he can make a comment

Comment: This code works fine in my other webpage and in this section of my page it's not. I wander why is it so?

Comment: Comments can contains multiple chracter that will break your sql query sintacsis. Consider to chagne your code to use parameter - you can see  @Kaf example.

Comment: I realized that.Thanks folks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be as you are directly passing user typed string. For example if user types something with single quote it will create an error.

Please avoid directly passing user typed strings with inline sql to the database. You are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Use a parameterised query to make your query safe and error free. You could amend your code as below.

```
//Your code
connection.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO [CommentTab]([Name],[Comments]) Values(@username,@comments)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", TextBox2.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
connection.Close();
Response.Redirect("~/Default5.aspx");
```